# PointRangeQuery (Lucene 6.2.1 API)

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to build a date seach filter for files that indexed like:

```
Long modTime = incomingFile.lastModified();  
doc.add(new LongPoint("date", modTime));
```

In the example, where I took this excerpt, I read "Use a LongPoint that is indexed (i.e. efficiently filterable with PointRangeQuery)". I cannot find any sane description how to build such PointRangeQuery for two dates defining timeslot. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
Query dateQuery = LongPoint.newRangeQuery("date", 1477567384000L, 1477567384500L);
```